# Seem to have banned my IP from my server

Tags: firewall, iptables

I can't seem to figure out the problem. I've checked the deny list in [CSF](http://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html), and even stopped it completely, as well IPTables. Somehow I'm still blocked from accessing my server. Currently I can access it from other IPs, so I'm pretty sure that's the problem (though I could be wrong, of course. I'm no expert)

So any suggestions on what it might be, and how I could fix it, would be heavily appreciated.

I've added my own IP to the hosts.allow file, and that didn't fix it. I also added it to CSF's csf.ignore file. Again, no luck.

I'm running CentOS 5.4

All access is being blocked, I can't even get ping requests back

**UPDATE:** My friend suggesting pinging a different IP on the server, and it responded.
So I switched the DNS to go to that IP instead, and while this is a decent *bypass* I'd really like to know how to *fix* it

Comment: What network access service is being blocked, RDP or SSH, or ??? For that matter, what O/S is your server running?

Comment: One second, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I went ahead and nullrouted the IP I couldn't connect to, and set the nameservers to a different IP. This solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `iptables -L` to check the default policy of the chains as well as any rules that are in place. `iptables -P` will modify the default policy (you'll want `ACCEPT`), and `iptables -F` will flush all rules.

Additionally, you'll want to check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` for any addresses in there that may match yours.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but still no joy. My iptables is allowing everything, and host.allow as well as hosts.deny was empty

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing your server - by name or IP?

If you are accessing by name is there an incorrect entry in /etc/hosts?

Comment: Both. Trying to ping it, and its not responding back. Works when I use a different IP to ping it, or access it otherwise. No, /etc/hosts is fine.